# Expression to set the textbox value in Sql Report Builder 3.0

Tags: reporting-services

I'm working on sql report builder 3.0 using SharePoint 2010 lists. I have a column with name Status and it has values like A & P. I added text box named as SetValue beside the status text box, now I need to  write expression for newly  added text box(SetValue) and set the  value as  0.5 when status is A. The following image shows what the final result should look like.

[image]

Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For SetValue expression you should use

```
=IIF(Fields!Status.Value = "A",0.5,"Other value")
```

Where other value is value for P.

Hope it will help.